# Calling a web service via the WSDL

Tags: java, android, web-services, wsdl

I have been following a tutorial to publish a web service which i have completed successfully

The wsdl can be found here - http://hotornot-hnwebservice.rhcloud.com/TomcatHotOrNot/messages?wsdl

The WSDL looks as follows;

```
<!--
 Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.1-b03-. 
-->
<!--
 Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.1-b03-. 
-->
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service.hotornot.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://service.hotornot.com/" name="ExposedFunctionsService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://service.hotornot.com/" schemaLocation="http://hotornot-hnwebservice.rhcloud.com:80/TomcatHotOrNot/messages?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="addMessage">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:addMessage"/>
</message>
<message name="addMessageResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:addMessageResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="ExposedFunctions">
<operation name="addMessage">
<input message="tns:addMessage"/>
<output message="tns:addMessageResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ExposedFunctionsPortBinding" type="tns:ExposedFunctions">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="addMessage">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="ExposedFunctionsService">
<port name="ExposedFunctionsPort" binding="tns:ExposedFunctionsPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://hotornot-hnwebservice.rhcloud.com:80/TomcatHotOrNot/messages"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Ideally i want to use android in order to invoke my web service. My assumption that the WSDL should describe the service to give an indicator to how to call the web service.

Can anyone help as to how i would call this web service from android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL describes the service i.e. its operations and structure. It also specifies if it is available over HTTP etc. All this information is enough to call the service. However you still need to go code the actual call to service.

Read [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html?ca=dat-) on how to call a web service from android.